# No 'the' in front of noun/title

Tags: definite-articles, indefinite-articles

I'm struggling to understand whether or not I can exclude *the* in front of **Countess' Suffering/Pain**? This is meant to be a title, as in a book title (but not necessarily that), and I was wondering if it's still proper English not to have it here? I'm not referring to a particular countess.

I know you normally say ***The* Countess' Suffering** but is **Countess' Suffering** still considered correct? It does sound rather unnatural to me.

Comment: If you're not referring to a particular countess, or to a particular dress, what are you referring to? A class of dresses called **Countess's Dresses**? I don't think such a thing exists. We really can't answer you without knowing more of the particulars.

Comment: @PeterShor I'm not exactly sure how to put it. I don't refer to any particular countess or dress. To be honest, **Countess' Dress** is the first such example that came to my mind. It could be **Countess' Sufferings** or **Countess' Emotions.** I know that, for example, ***The* Countess' Emotions** is correct (with 'the' in front of the noun). What about **Countess' Emotions**? Does it mean anything? Does it mean the same thing as ***The* Countess' Emotions**? Would it look unnatural to a native English speaker?

Comment: If there were a class of dresses called **Countess's Dresses**, I think you could leave off the title. Compare the titles **Ghost Story**, **Baker's Dozen**, and **Boy's Club**. But there's not, so I don't have any idea what **Countess's Dress** would mean.

Comment: @PeterShor Let's forget about 'dress' and focus on 'suffering' or 'emotions' instead. ***Countess' Emotions*** -- would this be considered correct, or would the meaning of it be understandable?

Comment: Pluralizing *countess'* (=countesses') might make it clearer that you have no particular countess in mind and that you're just trying to title a discussion of emotions that any/all countess/es might feel (if that's what you're after), in which case including "the" would not only be unnecessary, but maybe even wrong (cf: "noblewomen's rights/duties"). If you insist on leaving it singular, however, I think you'd need at least an indefinite article, i.e., "A Countess'[s] Emotions/whatever," which would perhaps be more consistent with the fact that you have no particular countess in mind.

Comment: Book titles can take poetic license and don't need to follow strict rules of grammar. Having said that, it would look odd to people without the article. But perhaps it would make perfect sense to anybody who had read the book. Or, if the name of the *character* is Countess, then it makes perfect sense—and *using* an article would actually be wrong. (Also, the more common way of punctuating the singular possessive here is currently **Countess's Suffering**. Your styling is not wrong, just less common. )

Comment: On the one hand, the Fowler brothers titled their first book on grammar and usage _The King's English_; on the other hand, Captain Kirk regularly announced entries to his official log of the expedition as "Captain's Log." Given those two camps, the question may be, Where do you want your title to fall?

Comment: @PapaPoule Right, so I'll go for the version with the article. Now, would **Duchess'** be correct here? It's quite a different question altogether, but I know you can drop the possessive apostrophe sometimes. Cosmopolitan did so [here](https://www.cosmopolitan.com/uk/fashion/celebrity/g3517/kate-middletons-outfits-style-fashion/). Now, they also spelled *duchess* with a capital D, so I'm not sure if that has something to do with the lack of the possessive apostrophe...

Comment: When you say that "you can drop the possessive apostrophe sometimes"  do you mean "you can drop **the S following** the possessive apostrophe sometimes"? I ask because the *Cosmo* link seems to be dropping **the S**, but not the apostrophe itself. Regardless, I don't think the capitalization matters, but rather, as mentioned by @JasonBassford, it's just a matter of there being 2 acceptable ways of punctuating singular possessives (when the singular word already ends with an "S"), i.e., 1-the way you & *Cosmo* do it, without an "S" after the apostrophe & 2-with that extra "S."

Comment: @PapaPoule To be clear, I personally follow *The Chicago Manual of Style* which *doesn't* recommend dropping anything (except in the case of a plural that ends in a *s*). If *Cosmo* suggests dropping something, then that's not what I said. (But I do agree there are different styles. I was just pointing out another one in my comment.)

Comment: @PapaPoule Sorry, I meant dropping the *s* after the apostrophe.  I'll probably go with the dropped *s* as it's just better for what I intend to do.

Comment: @JasonBassford Thanks, but I will most likely go with the other option, without the *s* after the apostrophe.

Comment: @JasonBassford Sorry for the confusion & thanks for the clarification.  All of my "YOUs" in my comment were directed at the OP and I mentioned and copied you just to acknowledge that you had already correctly pointed out that there are different styles.

Comment: You can’t exclude “the” in front of Countess' Suffering/Pain; not in a possessive, for the same reason you can’t drop it from The Countess alone. Something in there about gerunds and partiples…
The Suffering of Countess Hername or The Suffering of The Countess would be fine and dandy but does The Suffering of Countess work for you? 
Putting back her pain returns Countess’ Suffering which will never work, or Countess Hername Suffering” which relies on a poetic stretch.
You also cannot treat countess or baroness, marquess or duchess differently.

Comment: Quite separately, how can anything be “a title, as in a book title (but not necessarily that)”, please? Are you making a distinction between book and, say, play or film titles, or what, exactly?

Comment: @Sven Yargs, don’t you think languages including The King's English are abstract concepts but Kirk Captain's Log is a concrete thing?